# Run Django 1.9 on Python 3.5 instead of 2.7

Tags: python, django

I have Python 2.7 and 3.5 running on OSX 10.10 and also Django 1.9a -- which is support for both Python version. The problem is I want to run Django on Python 3.5 instead of 2.7. On some threads I found suggestions to run it by including the Python version e.g: `python3.5 manage.py runserver`, but I found this error:

`File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'`

FYI, I have no problem run Python3.5 on the same machine.

How can I solve this? thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

*Note: when I wrote this, Django 1.9 had not yet been released, and Django 1.8 did not support Python 3.5. Since then, Django 1.9 has been released, and Django 1.8.6+ supports Python 3.5. Therefore you can use the latest 1.8.X or 1.9.X with Python 3.5. Choose Django 1.8.X if you want long term support, or 1.9.X if you want newer features.*

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-with-pip) recommend that you create a virtual environment for the version of Python you wish to use, then install Django using pip.

On OS X, pyvenv is installed along with Python 3.

```
pyvenv djangodev # create the virtual env.  
source djangodev/bin/activate # activate it
pip install django
```

This will install the latest stable version of Django, currently 1.8.4. The Django 1.9 alpha has only just been released. If you are new to Django, you might have a smoother ride if you start with Python 3.4 and Django 1.8. It will be straight forward to upgrade later. If you definitely want to install the 1.9 alpha, you can install it using pip with

```
pip install django==1.9a1
```

Comment: I did install virtual environment and use it for this certain project, but somehow this Django version is running on my Python 2.7 instead of the latest version installed; Python 3.5. Just wondering how to make it run on Python 3.5 which is couldn't be achieved by run: python3.5 manage.py runserver command.

Comment: If you have activated the virtual environment, then the error `No module named 'django'` means that either django is not installed in the virtual environment, or you have created a virtual environment for a different version of python.

Comment: Thank you for spotting out the problem. I didn't install Django in correct environment, this far. Eventually, I follow along this this tutorial: https://godjango.com/96-django-and-python-3-how-to-setup-pyenv-for-multiple-pythons/ and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is one simple solution for Your problem without virtualenv or like that.
I use Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 installed with Homebrew.

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

To install Django for Python 3:

```
pip3 install django
```

To create Django project for Python 3:

```
python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Then You can execute all commands in this way:

```
python3 manage.py shell
python3 manage.py startapp page
python3 manage.py runserver
...
```

Or You can edit the manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python <— instead this line (first)
#!/usr/local/bin/python3 <— must be this one
```

And then You can execute all standard commands like:

```
./manage.py shell
./manage.py startapp page
./manage.py runserver
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Virtualenv is your friend. My life got so much easier when I started using it. You can create a virtualenv to use a particular version of Python, then set up your requirements.txt file to install all the packages you need using pip.

Answer (score 2):

We can specify the Python version in your virtualenv command.

```
virtualenv dev_FirstDj_py35 --python=python3.5
```

output

Running virtualenv with interpreter /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5'
New python executable in /Users/raja/test_first_py35/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /Users/raja/test_first_py35/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to install Django for 3.5, which is a separate install from Django for 2.7.

If you're using pip, make sure to use `pip3`. Otherwise, make sure to run `setup.py` using `python3.5`.