# How to run Django with Python 3.5?

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

After `source ./bin/activate`, on doing a `which python3.5` I get the following response

```
/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python3.5
```

I am using `Django 1.10.5` which according to their [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) supports `Python 3.5`. But on doing `python3.5 manage.py runserver`, I get the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

My project works perfectly fine with the default `python 3 (3.4)` in my Ubuntu 14.04 system. What is the issue here?

If it's any help, I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get) process to install `python 3.5`. I did not remove the existing `python3` from the machine as given in the end of the answer. I have both `python3` and `python3.5`

Comment: How did you install Django for the python 3.4?

Comment: `pip install django` inside the virtualenv

Comment: I did pip install django inside the virtualenv. Please note that this is an existing django project where I am upgrading from python 3.4 to python 3.5

Comment: So you already have virtualenv for Python 3.4 and now you create virtualenv for Python 3.5 in the same dir? Then perhaps `pip` still linking to Python 3.4. Try: `pip3.5 install django`

Comment: @flowfree ok i will try that and let you know

Comment: @flowfree i got pip3.5 command not found

Comment: Its better if you separate the virtualenv for Python 3.4 and 3.5. You can install python packages on both venv without problems and only activate the version you need.

Comment: @flowfree Yeah, I did that, and then it worked. Seems, we can't add a new python version into an existing virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, it seems we are not able to add a new Python version into an existing `virtualenv`. So, I created a new virtual environment using the command

`virtualenv -p python3.5 project-name`

Here `-p` specifies which python you want in the environment. Although the default `python` and `python3` are also included, which is a good thing.
I then copied my existing django project there, and installed all the dependencies with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. I used `pip3` because I am using `python3.5`.

After this, doing a `python3.5 manage.py runserver` worked like it's supposed to. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not installed django in the virtual environment.
You need to install all the dependencies in your virtual environment.
try using pip:

```
pip install Django
```

you can find more details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/install/.

Comment: I have already mentioned that its working fine with python 3.4. I did pip install django inside the virtualenv. Please note that this is an existing django project where I am upgrading from python 3.4 to python 3.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871265/run-django-1-9-on-python-3-5-instead-of-2-7 this question is similar to the one you asked. you may need to install version specific Django.